# Using Ancestors vs. StructuredProperty for relationships between entities

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I've read a lot about both [`ndb.StructuredProperty`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties#structured) in App Engine's NDB and the use of [ancestor queries](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/entities) to keep related entities grouped together.

However, I'm not sure I understand which situations would call for which strategy.

For example, if I have a User class, and a user can create **Links**, modify **Settings**, and earn **Achievements**, am I better off including Links, Settings, and Achievements as StructuredProperties inside the User object?

Or perhaps, I'm better off with separate entities that are grouped together with an ancestor key?

Let's assume that I'll be doing mostly reads, with occasional writes to this data.

`ndb.StructuredProperty` Example:

```
class Achievement(ndb.Model):
  date = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
  achievement_name = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)


class Link(ndb.Model):
  title = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
  url = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)


class Settings(ndb.Model):
  tile_layout = ndb.JsonProperty(required=True)
  email_updates = ndb.BooleanProperty(default=True)


class User(ndb.Model):
  user_name = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
  settings = ndb.StructuredProperty(Settings)
  links = ndb.StructuredProperty(Link, repeated=True)
  achievements = ndb.StructuredProperty(Achievement, repeated=True)
```

Ancestor grouping example:

```
class Achievement(ndb.Model):
  user_key = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=User, required=True)
  date = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
  achievement_name = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)


class Link(ndb.Model):
  user_key = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=User, required=True)
  title = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
  url = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)


class Settings(ndb.Model):
  user_key = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=User, required=True)
  tile_layout = ndb.JsonProperty(required=True)
  email_updates = ndb.BooleanProperty(default=True)


class User(ndb.Model):
  user_name = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you present as an example of a model based on entity group (with user as a parent) is actually just a model consisting of entities with the reference to a user entity (to its key). It is not an entity group. If you need to create an entity group, the parent's key must be part of the descendant's key.

```
user_key = ndb.Key(User, 'some_username')
a = Achievement(parent=user_key, achievement_name='some_name')
```

Anyway, when you consider to use entity group (entities with the common ancestor) for your data model, first think of it as a unit with strong consistency, transactionality, and locality.

You can find my answer to a question pertaining to entity groups [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21035003/should-i-put-the-user-in-the-ancestor-path-or-separately/21064897#21064897) and to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24715879/app-engine-data-modeling-for-comments/24716259#24716259).

A disadvantage of structured properties can be that they cannot be retrieved independently of the entity to which they belong.

The right model depends mainly on the way you need to work with entities.

1. Do you need to access the entities individually?
2. Do you require strong or eventual consistency for you entities?
3. How often will the entities be created/updated?
4. How many entities do you expect?
5. ...

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, pgiecek! **Settings** and **Links** entities will always be accessed along with the User, but **Achievement** entities will need to be accessed individually. As such, I think I'm going to use a parent key for the Achievements. Thanks for your help!